# What's a good linux program to make a depth map or 3d plane from a csv file of coordinates?

Tags: linux, csv, 3d-modeling, visualization

The title just about says it all...I have a list of evenly-spaced points in a csv file like this:

```
x,y,z
5,3,3.2
5,6,4.3
5,9,5.4
10,3,4
10,6,3.8
10,9,3.6
15,3,4.8
15,6,4
15,9,3.5
```

And I need a depth map or 3d plane of them. What is a good, simple program to use? Or, if it's not simple, how about some easy to follow instructions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard program for this sort of thing is `gnuplot`. The home page is

```
www.gnuplot.info
```

and there is an introduction to 3D plotting of data here:

```
http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/datafile-e.html#3dim
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [sqliteviz](https://lana-k.github.io/sqliteviz/#/) which I'm the author of. It is a free open-source offline-first PWA that allows you to convert a CSV file into SQLite database which runs in a browser with [sql.js](https://sql.js.org/#/). After that, you can get your data with a `SELECT` statement and create various [Plotly](https://plotly.com/javascript/) charts against the result set.

### Convert your CSV into a database

Choose your CSV file. Sqliteviz will show you the `Import CSV` dialogue with data preview.
[image: sqliteviz CSV import dialogue]

### Get your data with SQL

After importing all records from your CSV are available as rows in `csv_import` table. Get them all with `SELECT * FROM csv_table` query.
[image: sqliteviz query result set]

### Create a chart

After running a query you can switch the result panel to the chart mode and create a chart. I built some examples with your CSV.

#### 3D Scatter

[image: sqliteviz chart 3D Scatter example]

#### 2D Contour Hystogram

[image: sqliteviz chart 2D Contour Hystogram example]

#### 3D Mesh

It's a simple way in your case to create a surface. But unfortunately, it doesn't color depending on z-axis:
[image: 3D Mesh]

#### 3D Surface

This is a tricky case. The thing is that you need to have a pivot table. So your CSV should look like this:

```
x,y,z1,z2,z3
5,3,3.2,4,4.8
10,6,4.3,3.8,4
15,9,5.4,3.6,3.5
```

You can generate it with [Google sheets](https://www.google.com/sheets/about/), for example:
[image: pivot]
Now you can build a 3D surface. Note that the z-axis has a matrix consisted of `z1`, `z2` and `z3` columns.
[image: sqliteviz 3d surface]

Visit sqliteviz [documentation](https://github.com/lana-k/sqliteviz/wiki) for more details.